# tdlib: tdjson.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (python)

Tags: python, telegram

I successfully compiled tdlib https://github.com/tdlib/td

Then:

`$ python tdjson_example.py`

Output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "tdjson_example.py", line 10, in <module>`
 `tdjson = CDLL(tdjson_path)`
 `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__`
 `self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)`
`OSError: tdjson.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. Need set full path to the library:
https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/139

Answer (score 0):

for future readers, adding the full path is a "workaround" and not an actual solution, one think you could do is the following:

1. in [Instruction Generator](https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html) there is a section called `Install built TDLib to /usr/local instead of placing the files to td/tdlib.`, if you check that mark it will put the compiled Files in the `/usr/local/ {lib/bin/incldude}`
2. run `sudo ldconfig` and let it creates the Links for you!

#### ldconfig:

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
> shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
> line, in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and in the trusted directories,
> `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.  On some 64-bit architectures such as x86-64, `/lib`
> and `/usr/lib` are the trusted directories for 32-bit libraries, while
> `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64` are used for 64-bit libraries.
>
> The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so.
> ldconfig checks the header and filenames of the libraries it
> encounters when determining which versions should have their links
> updated.  ldconfig should normally be run by the superuser as it may
> require write permission on some root owned directories and files.

I worked for me! Hope it helps